# Youtube type annotation in html5 videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a video about style/trend tips and it features different clothes in it. I would like to link the clothes displayed in that video to its product page on online store. There is an option YouTube to do such thing using [Youtube Annotation](http://www.youtube.com/t/annotations_about) . But YouTube annotations does not provide linking to external link. So we cant link to google.com inside youtube annotations we can only link to other YouTube videos.

***So Is it possible to add YouTube type annotations to html5 videos ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `popcorn.js`

Demo link: [Demo Link](http://popcornjs.org/demos)

Documentation: [Docs](http://popcornjs.org/documentation)

Comment: Thanks a lot Swapnesh ! popcorn.js is awesome! Finally using this to solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try www.bittubes.com - we offer a tool fit for commercial use

Comment: that depends highly on your use-case - we figure u want to use it to increase profit and set our prices accordingly. please contact sales via hello@bittubes.com and my colleagues will figure something out to fit your needs