# Youtube Style video annotation/overlays (React)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, video, html5-video

Our organization has the need for what amounts to a YouTube style annotation system. Essentially, what we need is the ability to overlay text/images over video at specific times.

I did my best to search for existing React components or even existing vanilla JS libs for a reference implementation, but came up empty. If anyone knows of any resources I may have missed, the rest of this post may not even be needed.

I need help with the strategy to render these overlay components at specific times in the video, and making sure that we stay synchronized with the video's time. Since we are already using Redux, my initial thought was to ramp up on RxJS and redux-observable, and create a stream/observable using a timeout scheduler to avoid some sort of polling strategy. I'd also be listening for play/pause/skip events from the video to cancel/restart the timeout scheduler.

I've never used RxJS before, so I wanted to get some feedback before starting to ramp up on knowledge and moving to implementation. Are there any inherent flaws in what I outlined above? Is there a different strategy that may work better?

Thanks guys!

TLDR; Need help creating time synced components overlayed on video.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about React or RxJS frameworks, but about JavaScript. As soon as you have JavaScript solution, it would be possible to fit it in almost any framework. So the key question is -- is there an available JavaScript solution?

Well, such question is already answered. Check [here: "Youtube type annotation in html5 videos
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385822/youtube-type-annotation-in-html5-videos).